# Image not getting inside CSS shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm doing a pentagon with css shapes and for some reason, the image is not staying inside. I've tried many things such a position absolute and moving the image inside the  shape with the top and left properties but it does not work. It stays outside. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's the css for my pentagon:

```
.pentagon {
    margin-top: 200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    border-width: 130px 50px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.6) transparent;
}
.pentagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: -255px;
    left: -50px;
    border-width: 0 175px 125px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.6);
}
```

And here's the CSS for the image:

```
.logo-sponsor{
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; 
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yisera/xyoe1y0y/) with the demo.

Here's how it currently looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to change :

```
.logo-sponsor{
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    left: 20px;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v93rs9z3/)

But seriously, it's a bad idea to try to compose a logo like this : it's so much easier, and more powerful, to use an image. You could also use a character for this shape : ⬟

Comment: you mean doing both the pentagon and image on something like photoshop and then inserting it on the html as an image?

Comment: At least the pentagon. Those "CSS shapes" are just tricks, they always kick you in the back when you need to tune your styles.

Comment: Ok! Once in production I'll have a graphic designer do them then. I just need to have this demo finished for monday so I'm in a hurry.